# Show in --> System Explorer gives "Opening system explorer has encountered a problem. Execution of bus-send--print--reply--dest" error message

Tags: eclipse

I am using the 2022-06 (4.24.0) version. When I select "Show in" --> "System Explorer" for any file in a project I get the following error.
[image]

I had recently upgraded to this version and I did have this problem before. I realized that this error not only occurs for projects that were created in the old version but also in newly created projects.

I tried changing the path to nautilus "${selected_resource_parent_loc}" as suggested here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442562
but for me, this is not working either.

Does anyone else have this error and possibly a solution?

Comment: Which command line has to be executed on your system to open a file or folder in a system explorer like Nautilus? Could you please give examples for both, a file and a folder.

Comment: For folder it is: nautilus "/home/user". However, after your question, I also tried xdg-open since this was the default command and this worked. I am using ubuntu 18 and the default from Eclipse (Filemanage1) used to work fine. In any case, thank you very much your question gave me some idea where to look for :)